# Allow only certain classes to conform protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, protocols, swift-protocols

**Question**

I would like to create a protocol that can be implemented only by certain class.

**Example**

Let's say, there is a protocol `X`, so that only class `A` can conform to it:

```
A:X
```

Every `X` is `A`, but not every `A` is `X`.

**Practical Example**

I would like to create a `CollectionViewCell` descriptor which defines `CellClass`, its `reuseIdentifier` and optional `value` pass that descriptor to appropriate cells in controller:

*Protocol*

```
protocol ConfigurableCollectionCell { // Should be of UICollectionViewCell class
  func configureCell(descriptor: CollectionCellDescriptor)
}
```

*Controller*

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let descriptor = dataSource.itemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(descriptor.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ConfigurableCollectionCell
    cell.configureCell(descriptor)
    return cell as! UICollectionViewCell
  }
```

Now I need to force cast to get rid of errors, as `ConfigurableCollectionCell != UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: why not a subclass ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by casting to protocol and using another variable:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let descriptor = dataSource.itemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    // Cast to protocol and configure
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(descriptor.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let configurableCell = cell as? ConfigurableCollectionCell {
      configurableCell.configureCell(descriptor)
    }
    // Return still an instance of UICollectionView
    return cell
  }
```